# How to remove words that have the same letter more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to remove words that have more that have the same letter more than once. I have tried squeeze but all that is doing is removing words that have duplicate letters next to each other.

Here is the code at the moment:

```
array = []

File.open('word.txt').each do |line|                                               
  if line.squeeze == line 
    array << line
  end
end
```

Input from word.txt

```
start
james
hello
joins
regex
```

Output that I am looking for

```
james
joins
```

Any suggestions on how I can get around this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
array = []

File.open('word.txt').each do |line| 
  chars = line.chars                                              
  array << line if chars.uniq == chars
end
```

or shorter:

```
array = File.open('word.txt').select { |word| word.chars.uniq == word.chars }
```

Comment: Consider to always use `reduce` instead of local variables: `File.open(...).each_with_object([]) {}`. Also I guess the short version lacks `split`.

Comment: Why would you prefer `reduce` over `select` in this case? The second version uses `chars` too, therefore `split` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, for example:

```
re = /
  (.)  # match and capture a single character
  .*?  # any number of characters in-between (non-greedy)
  \1   # match the captured character again
/x
```

Example:

```
'start'[re] #=> "tart"
'james'[re] #=> nil
'hello'[re] #=> "ll"
'joins'[re] #=> nil
'regex'[re] #=> "ege"
```

It can be passed to `grep` to return all matched lines:

```
IO.foreach('word.txt').grep(re)
#=> ["start\n", "hello\n", "regex\n"]
```

or to `grep_v` to return the other lines:

```
IO.foreach('word.txt').grep_v(re)
#=> ["james\n", "joins\n"]
```